# What's the meaning of implicit path cost when calculating shortest path using dijkstra algorithm and how is it different from non-implicit path cost

Tags: graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I need to write the difference between implicit and non-implicit path cost as part of one of my assignments.I know what we mean by an implicit graph but have no idea about what is implicit-path-cost.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit path cost is the sum of the time moving to a vertex plus the cost of calculating the neighborhood of the current vertex which depends on the specific graph (problem) you are working with.
For example in a chess game you have a set of possible moves (future states/vertices) that are connected to the current state/vertex of the board, you need to calculate them before moving to one of them.